# Generating function for any series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, generating-functions

Given a summation series, is there any way to generate a function to find the value of  the sum of first n terms?

For example, we have, $\sum f(n)  = f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(n)$ . Now, I want to know if there is any $g(n) = \sum f(n)$

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: let me be specific. Just like we have $\sum_{k=1}^\mathbb{n} k$ = $n(n+1)/2$, Can we not have something for $\sum_{k=2}^\mathbb{n} 1/(k^2-1) $ ? If we can have, how to find that function?

Comment: What is "the polynomial/non polynomial function" of a summation series? A quick internet search didn't yield an answer.

Comment: that means any kind of function that can give the value of nth series.

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  I don't know what the $n^{th}$ series means, for example.  You mention generating functions, by which one normally means something like $A(x)=\sum a_n\,x^n$ where {$a_n$} is some sequence of numbers. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are looking for. The $n$th series is a function. If you want to find the value of it, you sum of the first $n$ terms.

Comment: Oh, the $n^{th}$ series means the sum of the first $n$ terms? Never heard that term before.

Comment: i am sorry, I actually meant the sum of the first n terms

Comment: did you mean sequence?

Comment: But of course there won't usually be a good way to write down the sum of the first $n$ terms of a general series.  Sometimes you can!  But lots of times there just isn't a simple, closed expression.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Please ask your sequence $(n^2 - 1)^{-1}$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(X)$ be the generating function of the sequence $(f(n))$ that is :

$$F(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)X^n $$

Then if $G(X)$ is the generating function of the sequence $(g(n))$ where :

$$g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(k) $$

Using the Cauchy product for generating function you can show that :

$$G(X)=\frac{1}{1-X}F(X) $$

Hint : show and use the fact that :

$$\frac{1}{1-X}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X^n $$

Let us look at your example. Assume we don't know that :

$$\sum_{k=0}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Now we set $f(n):=n$ and then $g(n)$ is the number we are looking for. Now :

$$F(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nX^n $$

And we easily see that :

$$X\times \frac{d}{dX}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X^n=F(X) $$

So :

$$F(X)=X\times \frac{d}{dX}\frac{1}{1-X}=\frac{X}{(1-X)^2} $$

Hence :

$$G(X)=\frac{X}{(1-X)^3} $$

Now since the sequence of coefficients of $\frac{1}{(1-X)^k}$ is known to be $\begin{pmatrix}n+k-1\\n\end{pmatrix}$ we see that :

$$\frac{1}{(1-X)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+2\\n\end{pmatrix}X^n$$

$$G(X)=\frac{X}{(1-X)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+2\\n\end{pmatrix}X^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}X^{n}$$

Using then the convention that $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}=0$ when $n=0$ then we have :

$$G(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}X^n $$

whence $g(n)=\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Now the same method allows you to compute a closed formula of :

$$\sum_{k=0}^nk^p $$

For any $p$. To apply this to your new example you "just" have to  compute the generating function of the sequence $(\frac{1}{n^2-1})_{n\geq 2}$.

Comment: I have edited the question giving specific example, please look at that and see if you come up with anything to help me.

Comment: @BeWakePandey, I edited my answer, you might not be conviced by it (this is absolutely your right), however I stick to the fact that generating functions is usually a powerful tool to get closed formula such as the one you are asking.

Comment: I could not get from where this came,

$G(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}X^n$

Comment: @BeWakePandey, I edited my answer.

Comment: Could you please shed light on this statement ? $G(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}X^n$
  Its not quite obvious to me.

Comment: Thank you @Clement so much. Though it did not directly help me at the beginning, I went through internet and came back and I understood everything. Thank you so much!!